# Uniqueness of solution for a specific ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Consider the following ode,
$xy'+y=1$, Determine whether this ode has a unique solution for $y(0)=b$ where $b$ is arbitrary, if it does, find the values of $b$.

My attempt: Solving the above ode, I get 
$xy=x+c$, where $c$ is a constant. This expression holds for all x and all y. So if $y(0)=b$ then $c=0$ which would imply $xb-x=x(b-1)=0$. Hence, either $x=0$ or $b=1$. Since $x$ is allowed to vary, I deduce that $b=1$. Since the ODE is linear, the solution, since it exists must be unique. Is there an alternative way to show this? Is my method correct?

Comment: What must $y(0)$ be if the ode is satisfied everywhere?

Comment: @copper.hat x must be non-zero, what else?

Comment: $0 y'(0) + y(0) = 1$ does not leave much room for bargaining...

Comment: @copper.hat how would I relate that to uniqueness and existence? may you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, it means there is no solution for $b \neq 1$. For $b=1$, $y(x) = 1$ is **a** solution.

Comment: In the equation $xb - x = 0$, you are using that $y = b$. But $y = b$ does not hold for all $x$. If fact, you only know that $y = b$ when $x = 0$. What you've shown is that *if* $y(x) = b$ for some non-zero $x$, then $b = 1$. But if only $y(0) = b$, this says nothing about $b$ at all. Of course, copper hat's derivation is more universal.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a solution that is defined at $x=0$ then setting $x=0$ we must have $0\cdot y'(0) + y(0) = 1$, or $y(0) = 1$.
Hence the only value of $b$ for which this system has **a** solution (defined at $x=0$) is $b=1$.

Note that $\hat{y}(x) = 1$ is a solution, so we can consider $y-\hat{y}$ and look for non zero solutions of $xn'+n=0$ passing through $z(0) = 0$ to
see if it is unique (obviously $x \mapsto 0$ is a solution).

Suppose $z$ is a solution, and consider the solution on an interval $[x_0,\infty)$ with $x_0>0$. It is straightforward to show that the system is Lipschitz and hence has a unique solution which
we can easily solve to get $z(x) = z(x_0) {x_0 \over x}$. Hence the solution on $x>0$ is
$z(x) = z(x_0) {x_0 \over x}$ and the only way we can have $z(0) = 0$ is if $z(x_0) = 0$,
or $z=0$.

Hence the only solution of the system is $\hat{y}(x) = 1$ for all $x$, in which
case the only valid $b$ is $b=1$.